# Render React Components Sequentially without re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to **dynamically** render React components sequentially **without** making previous components un-mount/re-mount the DOM.

Let me be more specific, I don't want `<ComponentB />` to render until `<ComponentA />` is finished rendering/mounting

This is how I'm doing it manually:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super()

    this.state = {
      finishedMounting: false
    }
  }

  isMounted(){
    this.setState({finishedMounting: true})
  }

  renderComponentA(){
    return <ComponentA isMounted={() => this.isMounted()}/>
  }

  renderComponentB(){
    if(this.state.finishedMounting){
       return <ComponentB />
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderComponentA()}
        {this.renderComponentB()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And then in `<ComponentA />`

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.isMounted()
}
```

Please don't respond with using a loop and passing back an array of all the components. That is mounting all the components at the same time. That is **not** what I am asking about.

Only when `ComponentA` finishes rendering, then `ComponentB` can start.

**Question:** How do I do this dynamically if I have **X** components I need to render sequentially?

Note: The reason I am doing this is because `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` take up a considerable amount of resources. And I need `ComponentA` to show first. But this is just an example. My real world scenario has more than just 2 components.

Comment: Your code doesn't work? If so, could you explain what happens?

Comment: @YonggooNoh Are you telling me it doesnt work or actually asking? Assuming my code does work, I want know how to do this dynamically as I stated. If I had 20 components, I don't want to writeout 20 functions to render them sequentially

Comment: No I mean, the codes in your question doesnt work?

Comment: It works. This is a simplified version of what I have. I'm not asking if my code is broken.

Comment: I think the question code looks good. but if you have many components, it would be better to make a module to render components sequentially. I can answer a little later if you want.

Comment: `renderComponent` seems like classic use case for HOC. See also https://blog.pusher.com/time-slice-suspense-api-react-17/